# elisp implementation of the "uniq -c" Unix command to count unique lines

Tags: emacs, uniq

If there is a data in region:

```
flower
park
flower
stone
flower
stone
stone
flower
```

`M-x some-command` should give me in different buffer:

```
4 flower
2 stone
1 park
```

This data can then be sorted by frequency or item.

Comment: No. count-matches is counting for single item.   `uniq -c` gives count for multiple items in the list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose a common method would be to just hash the strings and then print the contents. This approach can be easily accomplished in emacs.

```
;; See the emacs manual for creating a hash table test
;; https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Hash.html
(defun case-fold-string= (a b)
  (eq t (compare-strings a nil nil b nil nil t)))
(defun case-fold-string-hash (a)
  (sxhash (upcase a)))

(define-hash-table-test 'case-fold
  'case-fold-string= 'case-fold-string-hash)

(defun uniq (beg end)
  "Print counts of strings in region."
  (interactive "r")
  (let ((h (make-hash-table :test 'case-fold))
        (lst (split-string (buffer-substring-no-properties beg end) "\n"
                           'omit-nulls " "))
        (output-func (if current-prefix-arg 'insert 'princ)))
    (dolist (str lst) 
      (puthash str (1+ (gethash str h 0)) h))
    (maphash (lambda (key val)
               (apply output-func (list (format "%d: %s\n" val key))))
             h)))
```

Output when selecting that text

```
4: flower
1: park
3: stone
```

Comment: Nice and fast, this. Not sure you want that omit-nulls and line trimming behaviour, though?

Comment: I imagine the `maphash` sequence is undefined?

Comment: @phils right, if the sorting by key/value was desired I would put something like `(push (cons val key) result)` in the maphash function and a `(cl-sort results #'> :key #'car)` afterwards

Answer (score 2):

I suppose there are lots of approaches you could take to this. Here's a fairly simple approach:

```el
(defun uniq-c (beginning end)
  "Like M-| uniq -c"
  (interactive "r")
  (let ((source (current-buffer))
        (dest (generate-new-buffer "*uniq-c*"))
        (case-fold-search nil))
    (set-buffer dest)
    (insert-buffer-substring source beginning end)
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (let* ((line (buffer-substring (line-beginning-position)
                                          (line-end-position)))
                  (pattern (concat "^" (regexp-quote line) "$"))
                  (count (count-matches pattern (point) (point-max))))
             (insert (format "%d " count))
             (forward-line 1)
             (flush-lines pattern)
             (not (eobp))))
    (pop-to-buffer dest)))
```

Comment: Not least on account of this being entirely regexp based for no useful reason, this will not be a terribly efficient solution; but it should be an easy one to read/understand.

Comment: Moreover note that this process has O(n^2) complexity, vs O(n) for jenesaisquoi's hash-based approach.

Answer (score 0):

> It is similar to `uniq -c` in bash.

Then why not use `uniq -c`?

With the region highlighted, `M-| "sort | uniq -c"`, will run that command on the current region.  The results will show in the minibuffer and will be listed in *Messages* buffer.  Adding a prefix arg will insert the results into the current buffer.

Comment: `uniq -c` is  not available in  some environment natively.  That's the whole reason for the question.